# implemented cross post back using enter in a textbox but unable to do it after button is hidden

Tags: asp.net, postback

implemented cross post back using enter in a textbox but unable to do it after visibility of button is set to false.

Javascript

```
      function EnterEvent(e) 
    {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            __doPostBack('<%=Button2%>', "");
        }
```

CS File

```
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your button in a hidden div rather than setting Visibility:

```
<div style="display:none;">
<asp:Button id="btn" runat="server"/>
</div>
```

When you set `Visible="false"` on the server-side the control doesn't get rendered and doesn't make it into the client-side DOM, and thus can't be used by javascript.

Comment: still the error persists.
  Error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object